# Find Area Under a Graph

Tags: integration

Let $f$ be a function defined (piecewise) on the interval $[1, 2015)$ by the formula:

$$f(x)= \frac{2}{k(k + 2)} , \forall x \in [k,k+1), \text{where } k=1,...,2014.$$

Find the area of the region bounded by the graph of $f$, the x-axis and the lines $x = 1$ and $x = 2015$.

Comment: hint: 2/(k(k+2))=1/k-1/(k+2)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Mahbub. Could you give me a little bit more help? I don't understand how to even get started on this problem.

Comment: whats the area of the region bounded by the graph of f, the x-axis and the lines x = k and x = k+1 ?

Comment: OK, I have now found the area of the graph bounded by k and k+1 to be ln((k(k+3))/((k+2)(k+1)). Is this as far as i can go?

Comment: No its not, 'ln' will not come here, area will be 2/(k(k+2)) .1=2/(k(k+2)). Now sum k=1 to 2014 using my first comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)= \frac{2}{k(k + 2)} , \forall x \in [k,k+1), \text{where } k=1,...,2014.$$
$$\int_1^{2015} f(x) dx = \sum_{k=1}^{2014} \int_k^{k+1} \frac{2}{k(k + 2)} dx = \sum_{k=1}^{2014} \frac{2}{k(k + 2)} \int_k^{k+1}  dx = \sum_{k=1}^{2014} \frac{2}{k(k + 2)} $$
$$= \sum_{k=1}^{2014} \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k + 2}= \sum_{k=1}^{2014} \frac{1}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^{2014} \frac{1}{k + 2}   $$

Write out what you get for those terms.
$$\{\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2014}\} - \{\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2016}\}$$

Do you see what happens here?

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense.